# Restricting AD groups in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is there any way in `web.config` to deny users of certain AD groups access to the site?

I know this can be done in IIS but I am looking for a solution in `web.config` (if any).

Answer (score 0):

It's really the same thing.  The authorization settings you see in IIS are the settings in web.config.  Say you add a Deny rule for an AD group named Sales in IIS, you will see this added to your web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny roles="Sales" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This works both ways.  You can add the settings above to web.config and you will see the Deny rule in the Authorization section of IIS.

Comment: Hi Clint, this doesn't seem to work. Any other way? Members of AD group are still able to access the site.